# Matlab date help on x-axis

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a porkchop plot that looks similar to this:

[image]

The contour function used to make it has input arguments for the x and y positions that are serial dates (as that seemed to be required by MATLAB). Then I used the following command to get the format I want:

```
datetick('x', 2); datetick('y', 2);
```

The problem I am having is that when I zoom in on the plot the tick labels to not autogenerate and I can be left with no ticks on the x or y axis if I zoom in to use a weeks' date range for example.

I tried enabling `'auto'` for `XtickMode` and `YtickMode` but when I zoom in or pan after using those commands the relationship between the independent and dependent variables are lost for some reason (aka the dates don't stay with data like they do when you just have numbers on the x axis and zoom in).

Any ideas on how to solve this issue to get the functionality I'm looking for?

I have also tried the command `xtickformat('dd-MMM-yy')` but I get an error "Invalid numeric tick label format." when I use it with the contour plot.

Comment: could you please provide sample data and the full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no builtin method in MATLAB to do this. I use the [`datetickzoom`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15029-datetickzoom-automatically-update-dateticks) function from the MATLAB FileExchange. If you replace all instances of `datetick` with `datetickzoom`, it will automatically update the relevant axis labels when you zoom in.

Comment: This function from the fileexchange does what I want when I use the zoom button on the axes window (not when you use the mouse scroll wheel for some reason) Thank for you showing it to me.  I will use it going forward!  I am surprised the default matlab function does not implement this behavior as I see no reason a user wouldn't want this.

Comment: That's interesting, using the mousewheel to zoom updates the axes for me. What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: I have MATLAB version 2018B